# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, razor

I'm getting this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My Hosting provider is saying that MVC 3 is already installed and it works for one domain that s on the same server, but this domain is not working.

I saw lot of questions and answers related to this, but I want to avoid adding DLLs manually. If MVC 3 is installed properly. I wouldn't get this error. right?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `I want to avoid adding dlls manually` -- Why?

Comment: Why would I add the same DLL's to every project? MVC should add it to the GAC.

Comment: Sure, but if you can solve the problem by adding the DLL to the bin directory, do it and get on with life.  Otherwise, your hosting provider needs to fix the problem.

Comment: Isn't System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0 part of MVC 4?

Comment: What Ian is saying is that, if `System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0` is part of MVC 4 and not MVC 3, it would explain why MVC 3 is not finding it.

Comment: @IanGilroy yeah turned out that i had some mvc 4 pieces. wanna asnwer so i can mark ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, it sounds like there were some MVC 4 components being referenced by the app. Glad to hear that you've got a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after doing a delete and publish for a NON MVC website. Apparently something in my site is referencing System.Web.Helpers and that is copied over (even if I remove the reference from the project) but the following dlls were not copied in the publish:

- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor

I would prefer to remove all of these dlls from the project but the simple solution was to set the "Copy Local" property of each of the above dlls to True.